# Why doesn't glob:* match any path in PathMatcher?

Tags: java, regex, glob

Let's have:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\1.txt");
```

The following code prints "true":

```
PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("regex:.*");
System.out.println(matcher.matches(path));
```

but the following code prints "false":

```
PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:*");
System.out.println(matcher.matches(path));
```

Why?

I was expecting to have `true` in both approaches.

According to [Glob page from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), the wildcard `*` means:

> matches any number of any characters including none

**Details:**

- Java 8
- Windows 7

Comment: Rather than looking at Wikipedia for what that glob means, I'd strongly recommend [looking at the documentation for `getPathMatcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)). But it says something similar: *"The \* character matches zero or more characters of a name component without crossing directory boundaries."* Also note: *"The \*\* characters matches zero or more characters crossing directory boundaries."* Maybe you want `**` (don't know, never used `PathMatcher`).

Comment: Also, from the Wikipage you linked: `COMMAND.COM and cmd.exe have most of the common syntax with some limitations: There is no [...] and the * may only appear at the end of the pattern, not at the beginning.`

Comment: @JorgeCampos: `cmd.exe` on my Windows 8 system is fine with `*` at the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder 
Thanks. One more thing to add: running it in debug mode, the pattern value from matcher looks like this `^[^\\]*$` for `glob:*` and it looks like this `^.*$` for `glob:**`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @T.J Crowder said you should good to go with this :

```
PathMatcher matcher2 = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**");
System.out.println(matcher2.matches(path));
```

For more info see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)) which says :

> The ** characters matches zero or more characters crossing directory
>   boundaries.